# calling PHP multi dimensional arrays outside of foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an app that records months and years by one CSV entry,  i.e. db column named `answer1` is `jan,2008` and column `answer2` is `feb,2013`.  I want to use a specific month (jan) in html but it only gives me the last array data.

```
<?php
foreach ($row as $colName => $colValue )
  {
  if($colName === answer1 || $colName === answer2)
    {               
     //break apart date data
     $myArray = explode(',', $colValue);
     echo '<div id=" ' .$colName . $myArray[0] . ' ">test</div> ';//this works
        };
  };
```

?>

I'd like something like this in another php block later in the doc.

```
<?php echo '<div id=" '.$colName[answer2] . $myArray[0] . ' ">test</div> ';?>
```

Comment: add a `break` statement in your if

Comment: Strings should be enclosed by either single or double quotes.  What are answer1 and answer2?

Comment: I don't want to break out, I want the array info stored so I can call it later.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a lot easier. We're exploding (or pulling two substrings) from the original columns in MySQL before we get to PHP. Then you can use them however you would like:

```
$query = "SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(answer1,',',1) as a1_month,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(answer1,',',-1) as a1_year,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(answer2,',',1) as a2_month,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(answer2,',',-1) as a2_year from my_table";
$result = mysqli_query($query);


$answers = array();
$x = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    $answers[$x]['answer1_year'] = $row['a1_year'];
    $answers[$x]['answer1_month'] = $row['a1_month'];
    $answers[$x]['answer2_year'] = $row['a2_year'];
    $answers[$x]['answer2_month'] = $row['a2_month'];
 $x++;
}

print_r($answers);
```

If for some reason you still want the concatenated strings you can do this:

```
$answer1 = $answers[0]['answer1_month'].','.$answers[0]['answer1_year'];
$answer2 = $answers[0]['answer2_month'].','.$answers[0]['answer2_year'];
```

Comment: You can build the query with a `foreach()` out of an `array()`; If they're sequential you can you a `for()`;